# Confusing on Forwarded header

Tags: http, kubernetes, networking, http-headers

The new standard for headers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Forwarded) is confusing to me. I also tried reading the specification (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7239#section-4) and it's equally as confusing.

I have a basic configuration like this:

> client -> ingress (load balancer) -> reverse proxy -> service

The Forwaded header defines four fields as follows:

1. by - The interface where the request came in to the proxy server.
2. for - The client that initiated the request and subsequent proxies in a chain of proxies.
3. host - The Host request header field as received by the proxy.
4. proto - Indicates which protocol was used to make the request (typically "http" or "https").

What would each of these be set to in my case (excluding proto, that one is obvious)? The "for" seems to just be the client host, but then then I don't understand what it means by a "chain of proxies". I don't think it applies in my example, but I still want to understand.

My proxy has a registry that looks up all of my services, so as of now, I set this header inside the proxy. Is that where it is intended to be set? Thanks to anyone who can answer in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any Kubernetes Ingress Controller that implements this header. X-Forwarded-For and X-Forwarded-Proto are what basically everything uses.

Comment: According to the Developer.Mozilla docs, X-Forwaded-* is frowned upon.

Comment: They can say it all they want, but that's not the reality of the tools that exist :)